# How to change the name of images when user save them?

Tags: html, asp.net, browser

How can I change the name of images to website URL when user save them (*save image as*) , like this site :

[Simple Desktop Website](http://simpledesktops.com/)

for example the name of the image is : **man.png**

but when user save that the name of image will change to **mysite.com.png**

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I changed the image name manually

Comment: What code you do for getting that?

Answer (score 0):

This is just for your understanding

```
                string _strName = "mysite.com.png";

                System.Web.HttpResponse _response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                _response.ClearContent();
                _response.Clear();
                _response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                _response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _strName + ";");
                _response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("Img\\zentree_1.png")); //location of your Image file 
                _response.Flush();
                _response.End();
```

If that is not your expectation, then do reply with your code,
I believe i can help you on this.